# Dell Latitude 7390 - Intel UHD Graphics 620 support

Tags: debian, intel-graphics

I recently buy a refurbed Dell Latitude 7390 and install a Debian Bullseye on it. All works great with this laptop except the graphic card :

```
$ lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

To boot during installation, I have to add `nomodeset` kernel command line parameter, otherwise, the screen going black during boot and system crash (no answer to anything, I have to reboot).

After installation, I still can boot using the `nomodeset` parameter, but the graphic performance are really bad : no hardware acceleration, the HDMI output is not working, ... I also have a Dell D6000 USB-C dock and to use its HDMI and DP port to connect extra displays, I have to install DisplayLink driver (using the great https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian/ project). But after this installation, Xorg/Xwayland do not start if I boot using the `nomodeset` parameter.

After many try and long researches, I finally find a way to boot without the `nomodeset` parameter by replacing it by `dis_ucode_ldr drm.edid_firmware=edid/1920x1080.bin` parameters (the *1902x1080.bin* file was downloaded from https://github.com/akatrevorjay/edid-generator/ and put in */lib/firmware/edid* directory).

With these parameters, I can only boot my laptop if the dock is connected, otherwise, I still have the black screen. Without the dock, my only way to boot is the `nomodeset` parameter and so without X server.

I also have some trouble if I disconnect the dock after starting X : the screen freeze and the system not responding. It's certainly possible that the problem is related to the inability to boot without the dock, but it's difficult to verify.

I found this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620) which seems very close to my problem, but I already try to upgrade BIOS and firmwares available on Dell website and it changes nothing. About the workarround to downgrade the intel-microcode package, I try with available versions for Bullseye, but it advocate verion is quite old.

I don't think I'm the first to encounter this problem, so would there be someone to help me with this problem? I have no other idea to try to fix my problem, so any advise could be useful.

Thanks

PS : I also try to install a fresh Ubuntu and I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: First try kernel 6.0.6 (**without** any boot options). If it doesn't work please file a bug report here https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues

Comment: I try with the Debian Sid linux-image-amd64 (6.0.6) and it seem help : I successfully boot without any special kernel parameter with (and without) my dock connected. Thanks a lot for that @ArtemS.Tashkinov ! However, to fully try this solution, I have to build the evdi module (for DisplayLink support) and for that, I need the linux-headers package that come with a lot of dependencies that I don't want to install (at the risk of putting my installation in a unstable state between stable and sid). I hope this new version will arrive soon in backports to fully test that. Thanks again !

Comment: Finally it doesn't work. I had to stay on a v5 kernel because the DisplayLink driver didn't support v6 yet. Now it is, I retried a switch to v6. I was able to boot once in v6.0.0 (now available in backports), but only once. Since, at boot, I have again a black screen & crash. I also tried with a 6.1.8 kernel (from testing), not better. Worse, since then I can no longer boot into v5 with my workaround… I will try to open an issue, but it's hard to exposed and give details about my problem : a black screen its just black…

Comment: Could be a HW issue as well. It's highly unlikely that you're the only one with the issue that spans so many kernels.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov : No HW issue : I still have access to the original Windows installation and it's work fine on it. I just some others people with the same problem : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2006994 / https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000829

Comment: Please check this: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/4813 And do file a bug report if there's none.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks a lot for this link ! the workaround provided (`i915.enable_psr=0` kernel parameter) works well. I'm now in v6 kernel, with this unique kernel parameter (I removed all others) and after a lot of tests, It seem work very nice. I have now an unique configuration for with & without my dock and I can connect & disconnect it without freeze like before. I also test to suspend on RAM & disk and it's work as expected. Many thanks !

Comment: Thanks for the comment as well.